# Something I've not seen before with jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, syntax, selector

I've never seen a selector with this syntax; Can someone explain it to me?

```
var $select = $('<select>', { id: 'csvMarketSelector', name: 'csvMarketSelector' });
```

or

```
var $marketSelectorContainer = $('<div>').add($('<p>', { text: settings.marketLabel })
```

I understand settings.marketLabel; I've just not seen a selector like the above. Please no clowning. I searched for my answer, including on here, but couldn't find anything that helped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it just assigns the element to the javascript without adding it to the html. typically you would later append it to the page somewhere.

Comment: This is not a selector -- it's the [`$(html, attributes)` from of the `jQuery` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

Comment: ah, ok; that makes sense... thanks. If you want to answer this, I'll check it off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $select = $('<select>', {
    id: 'csvMarketSelector',
    name: 'csvMarketSelector'
});
```

**Explaination :**

`$('<select>'` :

Create a new element `<select>` wrapped in jQuery object

`{ id: 'csvMarketSelector', name: 'csvMarketSelector' }`

: set properties of that element (*i.e `<select>`*)

`var $select`

assign jquery object to a variable `$select`

---

Now you can use this variable like this -

```
$('body').append($select);
```

---

**More Info :**

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Answer (score 5):

The string here is not a selector. The `jQuery` function can also accept an [HTML string](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString), which it parses into a new DOM structure. The [possible formats](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) for this use of the `jQuery` function are:

```
jQuery( html [, ownerDocument] ) // htmlString, document

jQuery( html, attributes )       // htmlString, Object
```

The new DOM element is held in the jQuery list just as any other selected element would be. You can use [manipulation functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) to add it to the DOM of the page at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $select = $('<select>', { id: 'csvMarketSelector', 
                              name: 'csvMarketSelector' 
                            });
```

Just creates a select element , with **id and the name** attributes provided.

But the created element is not appended to the DOM yet.

You can use the `.append(` or any method that injects the HTML into the DOM

```
$('#div').append($select)
```

Answer (score 0):

The portion in the squiggly brackets is a hash of attributes that will be applied to the element that will be created by $(''). As Sushanth mentions it is not yet added to the DOM. You could also achieve the same result using alternate syntax by doing this:

```
var $select = $('<select id="csvMarketSelector" name="csvMarketSelector">');
```

The important thing that no one has mentioned yet is that you cannot mix and match these two types of attribute designations!

```
var $select = $('<select id="csvMarketSelector">', {name: 'csvMarketSelector'});
```

The above line will fail. You have to either put all of the attributes in with the tag, or in the hash associated with that tag.